# 'A selection is required' option under choices field of smarform in Ektron doesn't work as expected

Tags: content-management-system, ektron

Detailed requirement: I've a need to add 'Choices' field in an already existing smartform under which I've selected Listtype as a 'ListBox'. I've added few custom list items lets say 'A', 'B' and 'C'. I don't want a 'selection required' validation. For this, I didn't select an option of 'A selection is required' under Allow Selection field in the properties.

But after updating the smartform, when I'm trying to publish/save its Smartform content, it's throwing an error as a alert box that user has to select any value for the listbox. Its XML node structure can't be empty (for e.g. < MyListBox> < /MyListBox>).

I've tried to handle this through code, but I'm not getting the updated XML structure (after adding Listbox) for this Smartform content from the 'content' database table of Ektron. This means changes in the Smartform schema are reflecting in the Smartform content after update but not in the database.

Please advice. Did I miss something?

Comment: I forgot to mention the ektron version. I'm using CMS 400.NET Ektron V.8.02

Answer (score 0):

If you change the structure of a Smartform, it does not automatically update the content items that were created with it.  You would have to edit and re-publish each of those content items once you have updated your Smartform configuration.

If I understand correctly you want the option to not have any value selected at all?  If this is the case, you need to check the option "First item is not a valid selection".  Your first item can then be something like "Please select an option" with a value of "-1".

Then in your code if the value is -1 you know that no option was selected.